# Django Signals set signal to create a default avatar image on UserExtended model after registering User

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-3.2

I want to create an entry on UserExtended model after registering an user on Django default user model.

here is UserExtended model:

```
class UserExtended(models.Model):
    extended_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    avatar = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, default='Capture.PNG')
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

here is the view function that registering the user

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def register_user(request):
    data = request.data
    user = User.objects.create(
        first_name=data['name'],
        username=data['username'],
        email=data['email'],
        password=make_password(data['password'])
    )

    serializer = UserSerializerWithToken(user, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

here is the serializer

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    isAdmin = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    avatar = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_avatar(self, obj):
        avatar = obj.userextended.avatar.url
        print(avatar)
        if avatar == '':
            avatar = 'null'
        return avatar

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'email', 'name', 'avatar', 'isAdmin']

    def get_name(self, obj):
        name = obj.first_name
        if name == '':
            name = obj.email
        return name

    def get_isAdmin(self, obj):
        return obj.is_staff


class UserSerializerWithToken(UserSerializer):
    token = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'email', 'name', 'isAdmin', 'token']
```

here is the signal.py:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, pre_delete
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import UserExtended


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_extended(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserExtended.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_extended(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.userextended.save()
```

but the signal is not working to create an default avatar file for an new registered user

I am new. Please help me.

Comment: Did you import this `signal.py` in the app configs `ready` method?

Comment: no. how to do that. I never used signals. I am mysql developer. but I dont know how to use signals. I used to solve this problem in mysql with triggers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django does not look for any file named `signal.py`, etc. by default. Hence what is happening it that your signals are never registered (in fact the file you write them in is never run). The general solution to adding signals is to write them in a separate file and then import / register them in the app config's `ready` method.

In the app in which you write `signal.py` there should be a file `apps.py` in which there should be a class inheriting from `AppConfig` edit this class and add a `ready` method to it and import your signals there:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


# The parts marked as "Don't edit" mean to keep them as it already is in _your_ code and not copy it
class YourAppConfig(AppConfig): # Don't edit
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'  # Don't edit
    name = 'your_app'  # Don't edit
    
    # Copy only the code below
    def ready(self):
        # models, signals etc. are imported only here because otherwise the models might not be loaded yet
        from . import signal
```